# scrape data from Twitter use Spyder and Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, ipython

I tried to scrape data from Twitter using their API and Python 3.6, and I wanted to save the results in a text file to show it as a bar chart.

```
class listener (StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        print (data)
        savefile=open("C:\\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\twitter\twitter.txt","a")
        savefile.write(data)
        savefile.write("\n")
        savefile.close()
        return True
    def on_error(self,status):
        print (status)
```

It gives this error:

> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\twitter\twitter.txt'

How can I fix it?

Comment: you should use a raw string : `r"C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\twitter\twitter.txt"` or double the backslashes

Answer (score 0):

Either use a raw string: `C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\twitter\twitter.txt` or double the backslashes.

In general, after you have [registered your app,](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/terms/agreement-and-policy) do the following:

`pip install tweepy==3.3.0`

Then authorize:

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler

consumer_key = 'YOUR-CONSUMER-KEY'
consumer_secret = 'YOUR-CONSUMER-SECRET'
access_token = 'YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN'
access_secret = 'YOUR-ACCESS-SECRET'

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)
```

To read your own timeline:

```
for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.home_timeline).items(10):
    # Process a single status
    print(status.text)
```

List of followers:

```
for friend in tweepy.Cursor(api.friends).items():
    process_or_store(friend._json)
```

List of tweets:

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline).items():
    process_or_store(tweet._json)
```